# Predictive Model with Underlying Environment Trending

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, cross-section

I'm looking for some ideas / perspectives on what can be done when a predictive model is being trained on sample data that is taken over a period of time and the underlying environment is changing (over the course of the sample and continuing in out of sample data).

To be more concrete, I am building an [uplift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_modelling) model to predict the difference between treated response and control response in the mortgage refinance business in the US. The training data consists of individual level marketing campaigns Jan-Oct 2013. During this period the refinance market has cooled considerable (as interest rates started inching up and many of those that could refinance their mortgages may have done so already). Since the tracking of these marketing campaigns take so long, through October is all I have.

Normally, I would simply look to train the model on the latter half of this data where the environment is more aligned with current and short term future. However, to have any change of building a model, I need to pool together all the months (I am still holding out 30 percent of Jan-Sept for validation and all of Oct as an out of time sample) given the very low response rates (i.e. I have limited number of positive responses from the control group each month, which is only a fraction of the treated size).

Given that I need to include almost all of the months, can anything be done to allow the model to account for the changing environment and reflect the dampening of performance of the target variable over time (especially future predictions)? Please note, this is not a forecasting model / time series model. It is being treated as a cross sectional model to predict individual level performance on future marketing campaigns.